# HTML Purifier new line after shift+enter (As Intagram)

Tags: htmlpurifier

Sorry I'm not sure how to say this (I don't remember the exact term for that).
But if the user writes for example:

```
Hi

My Name is
Phil
```

The result should be (as it is in Instagram)

```
Hi
My Name is
Phil
```

I don't how I can change it with Purifier, because I get only one line:

```
Hi My Name is Phil
```

How should my config be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was easier than thought.

I changed the DOM Element (in my case span) with CSS to:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

And before getting my Result I'm going through this line

```
preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string);
```

It works perfectly